tun0 Interface Not Present in ifconfig After OpenVPN Configuration
I’m facing an issue with OpenVPN on my i.MX6ULL board. After configuring OpenVPN, I notice that the tun0 interface is not appearing when I run ifconfig. tun kernel module is already loaded and service file of openvpn client is also active.
Here is the reference link
